# Google Play on Android SDK

Tags: android

I want to install Google Play on my Android Emulator so that I can use Android apps on it as if it was an actual Android phone. I have heard of people doing this, but I myself do not know how it is done, and Googling it brings up nothing that is helpful to me.

Comment: @Ramhound I have found various articles online the claim to be instructions on how to do it, but I myself do not know how it is done. [Here](http://piotrbuda.eu/2012/05/installing-google-play-on-android-emulator.html) is one example of something that I found, but I do not understand any of what it is saying.

Comment: Google play gas changed a great deal since 2012 that article is old.  The article does tell you every apk you esquire to try it though just download those ( you are on your own for that ) and use the script file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to install apps from the app store in Android emulators without the need of the play store. To download the APK from the app store, use [this website](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/) which asks you to provide the URL of the page on the Google Play store of the app you want to download. After you have downloaded the app, launch your emulator and open a command prompt or terminal and `cd` to the location of your Android Debug Bridge installation. On my computer, this location is `C:\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe`, so:

```
cd C:\android-sdks\platform-tools
```

Afterwards, installing the app can be done by typing `adb install` followed by the location where you are storing the APK. For example, if I want to install `myAwesomeApp.apk` which is located at `C:\myAwesomeApp.apk`, I would type:

```
adb install C:\myAwesomeApp.apk
```

After a few moments, your app will be installed in the emulator.

If you have minimal or no experience working with commands, please note that if your filepaths contain spaces, you will need to surround them in quotes, for example:

```
cd "C:\my\file\path\with spaces"
```